Understanding に巻き込まれる
Looking up the meaning of 巻き込む gives two entries:

❶ 巻いて中へ入れる。
「ノリに酢飯とかんぴょうを━」
「機械に服を━・まれる」


❷ ある事態や関係に引き入れる。
「相手を自分のペースに━」
「紛争が兄弟を混乱に━」
「事件に━・まれる」

It seems like when 巻き込む is used in sense of both ❶ and ❷, に marks "destination," not passive agent, is that right?
Also, I got an impression that sometimes the passive form of 巻き込む from ❶ is a spontaneous verb, not 巻き込む in passive form. It is clear (?) from the example 機械に服を巻き込まれる. The same goes for this sentence 大波に巻き込まれる. Is my intuition correct?

In a passive sentence in the first, literal sense, such as 機械に服を巻き込まれる and 大波に巻き込まれる, the particle に could be understood as denoting both the agent that causes the motion of "rolling" and the place where the patient ends up "rolled in" at the same time. I think this is because the 込む part in this verb itself implies a movement towards the one doing the "rolling" like the English adverb "in" also might.
While a sentence like 兄に布団に巻き込まれる is possible, it doesn't sound quite as natural as, say, 兄に押し入れに押し込まれる.
Using に for an animate agent is fine in the second, figurative sense.

相手に自分のペースに巻き込まれる

When an inanimate agent rolls something into something that is different from itself, it should be marked with によって.

酢飯とかんぴょうが機械によってノリに巻き込まれる。


兄弟は紛争によって混乱に巻き込まれた。


This is interesting that に sometimes can refer to both passive agent and "destination." This is the same に found in 川に流される?

@JohnDavies - 大波 in 大波に巻き込まれる is more clearly an agent. The "destination" is only implied. 大波が（人を）巻き込む is completely fine while 川が（人を）流す sounds a bit artificial. On the other hand, 海に巻き込まれる doesn't sound as natural as 川に流される.
